# Howto Resize an android ShapeDrawable Directly Via Code without creating another

Tags: android

```
 I am able to resize a drawn ShapeDrawable but it Creates another shape with the       following code how can I just resize the original ShapeDrawable
```

I am Writing a drawing app and have been stuck on this for a couple of days
any help would be greatly appreciated
 even a small nudge in the right direction please.

```
     public void Resize(Context context){     
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);  
        //this.setOnClickListener(this.mDrawablecircle); 

        int x =Integer.parseInt("0"); 
        int y =Integer.parseInt("0");
        int cirw =Integer.parseInt("20"); 
        int cirh =Integer.parseInt("20"); 
        mDrawablecircle.getPaint().setStyle(Style.valueOf(Shapestoollistactivity.mf));
        mDrawablecircle.getPaint().setColor(ColorPickerActivity.thecolor);
        mDrawablecircle.getCurrent().setBounds(x, y, x + cirw, y + cirh);
        mDrawablecircle.draw(mCanvas);}
```

// Update this is what I ended up doing still not 100%
    // but somewhat working may help someone else

```
    public void Resize(int newWidth){     
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);  
    int x = (int) mPosX; 
    int y = (int) mPosY;
    width = mDrawablecircle.getBounds().width();  

    height = mDrawablecircle.getBounds().height();  
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;  
    float ratio = ((float) mDrawablecircle.getBounds().width()) / newWidth;  
    int newHeight = (int) (height / ratio);  
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;  
    matrix.setTranslate(mPosX+40,mPosY+40);
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);  
    postInvalidate();}   


  // and in In onDraw  
  // I Changed this:       mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,0,0, mPaint);
        //  to:       mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,matrix, mPaint);

hope this helps some one else Im sure there is a better solution 
but I cant seem to  find a better one as of yet feel free to chime in and 
correct me Please this at least will do the resize of a shape drawable without
creating a new one but it resizes the whole canvas  NOT WHAT I WAS AFTER
I would like  to be able to resize individuale shapedrawables
Which are created from java code not xml or from a resource.
```

Comment: Why do think a new instance of mDrawanlecircle will be created? Or are you seeing a new circle drawn?

Comment: Im seeing a second circle drawn

Comment: I also tried mDrawablecircle.getShape().resize(20, 20); With the same results

Comment: You are not doing the resizeing of the view properly. See my answer below. To keep things simple and tidy, never draw views outside onDraw Method. To trigger ondraw method use Invalidate method to redraw the view/drawable etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling draw on mDrawableCircle like that do the following. I assume that your class is a custom view.

```
    public void Resize(Context context) {
          .....
       invalidate();
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.onDraw(paint);
       //Do the drawing of the drawable here. 
    }
```

Comment: Ill try that as this is a drawing app I am drawing many shapes and pictures as well

Comment: Well I Tried that and still drawing 2 shapes one smaller than the original and not resizeing the original? by the way thank you very much for your response

Comment: Yes My Class is a custom View I tried calling Resize(context) in on draw but Im Still Seeing 2 images I Also Added the invalidate this one has really got me stumpted thank you very much for your response Its getting late here I will hack at it some more and give it another shot tommorrow